# unlink doesn't work ... file is writable and exist

Tags: php, file

I have an image sharing website and recently I've noticed I can't delete some of my images via script.

My file is writable and exist (so it's not a permission issue), but why can't I unlink it?

```
echo    $file = base_path('./files/images/2013/11/TubeCom_3313c73ab7924b1f36ee49ad0979a16ad490f9a2.jpg');
echo    is_writable($file) ? ' @is_writable ' : ' !!is_writable ';
echo    is_file($file)     ?   ' @is_file ' : ' !!is_file';
$res = unlink($file);
var_dump($res);
```

Here is the result:

```
    ./home/siteecom/domains/site.com/public_html/files/images/2013/11/TubeCom_3313c73ab7924b1f36ee49ad0979a16ad490f9a2.jpg 
    @is_writable @is_file bool(false)
```

I've also tried relative path ... didn't work

Comment: To delete a file, you need write access to the parent folder. Also,  enable `display_errors` and set `error_reporting` to `E_ALL` as `unlink()` **will** tell you what went wrong via an `E_WARNING` level error

Comment: Can you show the output of `var_dump(is_writable(dirname($file)));` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recently run into an issue like this before.
Firstly you'll need to turn on error reporting as `unlink()` will tell you exactly what's wrong:

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

You'll want to make sure the directory that contains the file you want to delete is `writable` (*please supply the chmod permissions for us to help furthur*).

You should look into using [`realpath()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.realpath.php) to get the absolute path to the file. (I don't think this is the issue as it doesn't throw a file not found error).

---

Your problem is almost certainly related to incorrect permissions for the directory you're trying to delete in and also the script thats trying to delete said files.

If you could supply those permissions of both with something like:

```
echo "Directory = ".substr(sprintf('%o', fileperms(DIRECTORY)), -4) . "<br />";
echo "PHP File = ".substr(sprintf('%o', fileperms(SCRIPT)), -4) . "<br />";
```

We can try and help you further.

Comment: thanx , there is something wrong with my directory , although it's owner issue not directory permission as all dirs have 755 perm , but some have different owner

Comment: @max That would've been my next suggestion, to use something like `chown` to change user to try delete.

Answer (score 2):

You probably missed that in order to delete a file you'll need write permissions to the file *and* it's ancestor folder. Make sure that the directory `./files/images/2013/11` is writable by PHP.